# How to import already existing sheet from another excel file into mine?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have problem - I created an excel file through `xlsxwriter` library but now I have one porblem. How to import to this file sheet from another excel file?

Here is piece of code:

```
SHEET_NAME = 'Foreign_holders'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Holdres.xlsx')

def create_sheet(workbook):
   worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(name=SHEET_NAME)
```

The problem is that I need to import all info from the sheet with all data and formulas from another excel file, which name, for example `'Holdres2.xlsx'`. Because when I just copy it and paste on `Holdres.xlsx` - it just removed copied sheet and replaced with empty after I run the code.

Comment: open both files, copy data, and save them.

Comment: maybe you have to open file in 'append' mode? Or maybe you should add with new name to keep previous?